# How do you factor a division problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, circles, factoring

I tried taking out $2\pi r$ from $$\frac{2\pi r h}{2\pi rh+2\pi r^2}$$
Now I have $$2\pi r\left(\frac{h}{h+r}\right)$$

But the final answer said it's: $$\frac{h}{h+r}$$

If we're left with $h/(h+r)$ without the $2\pi r$ how would we reverse and get back to

$$\frac{2\pi r h}{2\pi rh+ 2\pi r^2}$$

Comment: Notice that $\frac{ax}{ay}=\frac{a}{a}\cdot \frac{x}{y}=1\cdot\frac{x}{y}=\frac{x}{y}$.  That is to say, if you factor the same amount out of both the numerator and the denominator simultaneously, they cancel.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

There is a copy of $2 \pi r$ in the numerator and another at the denominator.

$$\frac{2\pi rh}{2\pi r h + 2\pi r^2}=\frac{(2\pi r)h}{(2\pi r)( h + r)}$$

cancelling the common term out give you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can factor out $2\pi r$ from both numerator and denominator which then cancel each other out.  Like $\frac26=\frac{2\times1}{2\times3}=\frac13$.